# A non-Hermitian-Einstein vector bundle over a compact homogeneous Kahler manifold?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, lie-groups, kahler-manifolds

An Hermitian-Einstein $V$ vector bundle over a compact Kahler manifold $M$ is an Hermitian holomorphic vector bundle whose Chern connection $\nabla$, with curvature $F_{\nabla}$, satisfies
$$
\Lambda F_{\nabla} = \lambda \mathrm{id}, ~~~ \lambda \in \mathbf{R},
$$
where $\Lambda$ is the adjoint of the Lefschetz operator. What is an example of a non-Hermitian-Einstein vector bundle over a compact homogeneous Kahler manifold?

Comment: A Hermite-Einstein vector bundle is semi-stable, hence it suffices to give an example of a vector bundle which is not semi-stable, e.g. $\mathcal{O}\oplus \mathcal{O}(1)$ on $\mathbb{P}^1$...

Comment: you question is not well-posed..what do you mean by non Hermitian-Einstein?